# Tabs vs Space indentation

Tags: coding-style

If you read any coding style guide, there is a big chance you will see a recommendation on using spaces instead of tabs for indentation. Some guides explicitly say: never use tabs.

I know that there is a risk of starting a nuclear war about tabs vs spaces. It is surely not what I intend. What I do intend, however, is to ask you if there is any good reason for this recommendation. Why does everybody keep saying that spaces are the best way to indent code?

Comment: Btw, if anyone votes to close the question, would be helpful to know _why_ was that. Thanks!

Comment: This has been done to death on PSE: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/57/tabs-versus-spaceswhat-is-the-proper-indentation-character-for-everything-in-e for example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft Internal Coding guidelines: don't use tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784481/microsoft-internal-coding-guidelines-dont-use-tabs)

Comment: "Space Won" ( https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/03/07/tabs-versus-spaces-spaces-won/ ) has pretty solid argument (backup up by http://evadeflow.com/2011/03/tabs-vs-spaces-in-the-21st-century/ ). Basically: You can use ONLY SPACES and that is ok. Spaces will look the same everywhere (every computer and every place in the line). TABs cannot be used to align, just to indent. That is pretty confusing to teach new programmers. And it looks different on other computers configurations. So, keep it simple: 2 spaces.

Comment: "Why does everybody keep saying that spaces are the best way to indent code?" 2 reasons: 1. tradition 2. literally nothing else

Comment: @rwollr: perhaps you'd care to make *specific* technical comments on the pros/cons of "mixing of tabs and spaces" per my answer, or the variability factor mentioned by Starkey, rather than saying *"literally nothing else"* despite things listed in answers here for >3 years?  As for tradition - it was very much traditional to use tabs in assembly language programming on many systems I worked on, so I don't buy that at all.  Back then, the 8-columns-per-tab was workable for separating labels from instructions from arguments, but for 3GLs the code layout differs, as do width preferences.

Comment: @TonyD tabs for indentation, spaces for alignment. tabs for indentation, spaces for alignment. tabs for indentation, spaces for alignment. tabs for indentation, spaces for alignment. tabs for indentation, spaces for alignment.

Comment: @TonyD http://puu.sh/jiKhj/d8bb6d6c08.png as you can see, none of the "problems" referenced in either answer actually exist or make any sense. just reactionary dogma in support of the oppressive spaces status quo.

Comment: @TonyD if you want specific technical arguments in favor of tabs over spaces as opposed to just explaining why all the complaints about tabs are nonsense, consider that assuming an indent width of 4 spaces, average indent depth of 2, and average SLOC length of 40 characters, the source code is being bloated by 20% whitespace. this is non-trivial in environments such as web development (assuming minification is not ideal, which it frequently is not in non-production). furthermore, code readability/customizability (custom tab width) and navigation (1 character vs 2-8) is greatly enhanced.

Comment: @TonyD this is not to mention the myriad caveats inherent to spaces that many argue to no end "don't matter" because many editors mask said caveats. it's true that in any editor worth anything, you can configure tab to insert as many spaces as you need instead of having to press the space bar repeatedly, and whitespace navigation is vastly streamlined. however, as the two answers below constantly remind us, we are not always at liberty to use our editor of choice. the inherent clunkiness present in the use of spaces over tabs therefore cannot be easily understated.

Comment: @rwollr: not that I agree with you, but that's a much more useful contribution, and would be better off in your own answer than cluttering up things here....

Comment: @TonyD this question is locked to new answers.

Comment: not that there even is anything to agree or disagree with considering i kept my argument to objective fact

Comment: [Developers Who Use Spaces Make More Money Than Those Who Use Tabs](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/15/developers-use-spaces-make-money-use-tabs/)

Comment: I recently had a debate on the topic, and learned how using spaces can be a real accessibility issue for some people with visual impairment: https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/c8drjo/nobody_talks_about_the_real_reason_to_use_tabs/

TLDR: they use tabs so they can accommodate their needs, otherwise they need to always convert spaces to tabs, and then reconvert tabs to spaces before committing.

Answer (score 9):

Getting tabs to look right depends heavily on the configuration/choices of all the software the source code might be displayed or printed by.  If you have a restricted set of such software and find that's not a practical problem for you, that's great - go for it if you see value.  But, be aware that when a line is indented with tabs, then continued on subsequent lines where you want indentation based on the position of an opening parenthesis, to line up quotes etc. - you'll be mixing tabs and spaces in a way that's visually impossible to verify the correctness of (unless your editor shows tabs differently).  Countering that, using arrow keys to cross tabs, or delete, can be faster but also more confusing and frustrating.  It's rare for different people using different tab widths to work cleanly on the same code, which is perhaps the main promise of tabs.  Personally, I use spaces.

Comment: +1 for the mixing of tabs and spaces argument

Comment: One could also remark, though, that attempting to line things up between lines is a foolish thing to try anyway, since the part of the first line you're trying to line up with may change due to a rename. See Kevlin Henney's talk, Seven Ineffective Coding Habits on a "perfect" alternative that makes any "lining things up" excuse fall flat.

Comment: @JacobZimmerman sounds like yet another religious war :-).  Personally, I like to keep my options open and do what I think is on balance optimal in any specific bit of code.

Comment: @Tony Delray I'm not trying to be religious about it, and I can respect your pragmatism about it, but I simply haven't seen a really good reason to use spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: @JacobZimmerman: if there was a _really_ good reason either way, it wouldn't be a topic of endless disagreement - there can still be a choice that's slightly but significantly better on average, especially when working in large and diverse teams using different editors, formatting tools, printing systems etc..  Henney's points equally applicable to 80-column coders, and yet there are environments where it's a net win to put in the reformatting effort due to the editors and tooling being used.  Anyway, readers with strong reasons in their code environment won't need to look here for guidance.

Comment: I recently had a debate on the topic, and learned how using spaces can be a real accessibility issue for some people with visual impairment: https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/c8drjo/nobody_talks_about_the_real_reason_to_use_tabs/

TLDR: they use tabs so they can accommodate their needs, otherwise they need to always convert spaces to tabs, and then reconvert tabs to spaces before committing.

Comment: @fcole90 Yes, it's a *usability* issue that's treated as a purely *technical* issue. In graphic design, margin and whitespace are important. They help the viewer quickly locate visual information. When text or other information is packed too closely together, it can take longer to identify. I'm not convinced that coding is any different, and I'm more productive when I can infer code structure at a glance. Vertical spacing/grouping is equally important. While tabs work well with a decent code editor, semantically neither spaces nor tabs are ideal. We need a new char with user-adjustable width.

Answer (score 8):

Tabs can be a different size on different computers and printers. The code might look great on the original computer, but on another computer or printout the spacing might look all weird.

With spaces, the code will look the same regardless of the computer.

Comment: yes, but the advantace of tabs, however, is that you can set the width of the tab without actually affecting the source.

Thanks for the printing explanation. Didn't thinked about that (since i don't print code)

Comment: I swear I don't want a flame on this. I want to hear more advantages of spaces over tab. (I personally use spaces for indentation, mostly because i followed guides, but some friends urges me to switch to tabs; i'm not able to bring any other valid argument other than `is what big guys do`)

Comment: usually a [tab] is 4x [space], but also can be 4.5x [space] depending on the local setup as Starkey stated. Then you throw in nonproportinal fonts into the mix and you can watch Pershing 2 rockets lifting majestic into the sky... :)

Comment: What if two developers have two different indentation preferences? They can both just set the tab width to whatever they like. With spaces, however, this is impossible.

 The argument that "with spaces the code will always look the same" is therefore invalid, since many times looking the same is not what different developers with different preferences will intend.

Comment: No matter if you are using tabs or spaces. Google use spaces in its  coding style that doesn't mean you can't use tabs. Do what make your code more understandable for you and other too.

Comment: @sschrass at that point, spaces aren't really helping, either.

Comment: @Frankey but why do you want to "start at any point"? See Kevlin Henney's talk, Seven Ineffective Coding Habits to see why I disregard that argument.